# addremove() jQuery not functioning

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am attempting to do a simple addRemove on click and it is not working.   I have done considerable research here and at jQuery and tried several approaches for some reason the code is simply not working. Please assist...

HTML

```
<div class="theme-slider-wrap">
    <div id="themeSlider" class="hide"><b>Test</b></div>
    <div id="toggleitnow"><i class="fi-x-circle size-18"></i></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hide{display:none;}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $( "#toggleitnow" ).click(function() {
    $( "#themeSlider" ).toggleClass( hide, addOrRemove );
});
```

Comment: Where is `addOrRemove` defined?

Comment: what is `addOrRemove`..?

Comment: addOrRemove was found here: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: addOrRemove is boolean value. Copy pasting will cause this error to your code

Comment: @petebolduc That explaining what to place in the parameters. It's not a value in the same way `className` isn't. It's expecting a boolean there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try two approaches on by applying class

1)Using hide class and then toggling

**HTML code**

```
 <div id="themeSlider" class="hide"><b>Test</b></div>
```

**JS code**

```
 $( "#themeSlider" ).toggleClass("hide",addOrRemove); //jQuery code
```

where first parameter is className which you need to toggle and addOrRemove is boolean value;

2) Without using hide class

**HTML code**

```
<div id="themeSlider"><b>Test</b></div>
```

**JS code**

```
 $( "#themeSlider" ).toggle(addOrRemove); //jQuery code
```

**PROBLEM**
addOrRemove is undefined value you are using in your code

**SOLUTION:**
Give some boolean value and try

```
var addOrRemove=true
```

Comment: Its just snippet. I will refactor it.

Comment: I created the var addOrRemove=true and changed the function toggleClass() to toggle() and it worked to remove the class .hide... but when I click it again it does not add the class back

Comment: Yes addOrRemove is dummy value. Once it is true then to get back toggle it should be false again.

Comment: I changed the function back to toggleClass() and it is working both ways... thanks for your assistance... really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The name of the classes you pass to the [`.toggleClass` function](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) need to be strings:

```
$( "#themeSlider" ).toggleClass( "hide", addOrRemove );
// Name of the class as a string --^
```

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

> **`.toggleClass( className, switch )`**
>   `className`
>   Type: **String**
>   One or more class names (separated by spaces) to be toggled for each element in the matched set.

---

In addition, it's not too clear where your `addOrRemove` boolean variable is defined. You'll need to ensure that the variable exists and is available in your scope.

Answer (score 0):

in the jQuery documentation, the addOrRemove has to be replaced by a boolean value.

- If it's true, this will add the class.
- If it's false, this will
  remove the class.

I think, in your example, you want to toggle the hide class, so you have to use the simple version of toggleClass function.

Your code should be like that:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $( "#toggleitnow" ).click(function() {
        $( "#themeSlider" ).toggleClass("hide");
    });
});
```